# How to deploy more than one application using spring boot in same tomcat or any servlet container?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on one new **Spring-boot** project. In my project ,there are 4 projects and they will interact with each other through rest webservice. I want to deploy them in same tomcat.Can anybody please tell me how to do this?

Comment: It's not different to any other web application. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Yes,I am trying to deploy my application in standalone tomcat but it's throwing below mentioned Exception.                                                                     SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/restfiddle]]

Comment: Ok, if you have a specific problem, then you should add the relevant error messages to the question (and the part that you posted is not relevant, because it is not the real error).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must not be assigning different server ports to your all four apps and hence all of them are getting assigned the default port of 8080 and the moment 2nd app is deployed you start getting that exception. You have following two option to address this issue :-

Assign different ports to all apps in respective application.properties (or yml) file as :-

```
server.port = 8081

server.port = 8082

server.port = 8083

server.port = 8084
```

and access these apps on urls localhost:8081, localhost:8082, localhost:8083, localhost:8084

OR

let spring dynamically assign ports to your app by having this config on all apps application.properties(or yml) file:-

```
server.port = 0
```